# Sorting an array in perl and returning the result in one line

Tags: perl, sorting, scripting-language, interpreted-language

I am trying to sort an array in Perl from Z to A and return the sorted array in one line.

What I am doing is:

```
sub mainTexts {

    my @texts = ();

    print ("Enter text 1: ");
    my $text1 = <STDIN>;
    push @texts, $text1;
    print ("Enter text 2: ");
    my $text2 = <STDIN>;
    push @texts, $text2;
    print ("Enter text 3: ");
    my $text3 = <STDIN>;
    push @texts, $text3;

    my @sorted_texts = sort { lc($b) cmp lc($a) } @texts;

    print "Your texts are: ", @sorted_texts;


}

mainTexts();
```

This results in:

> Your texts are: ZSAHS
>
> FGDSJ
>
> ABCNA

While the result I want is:

> Your texts are: ZSAHS FGDSJ ABCNA

Any clue how to achieve this from the code above? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input from the readline operator (`<>`) will generally contain the newline at the end of the line, so you need to pass it to [chomp](https://perldoc.pl/functions/chomp). Then, you can interpolate the array directly into the string rather than passing it as additional arguments to print. Interpolating an array separates each argument with [$"](https://perldoc.pl/variables/$") which defaults to a space, while separate arguments to print are separated by [$,](https://perldoc.pl/variables/$,) which doesn't have a default, but is commonly set to a newline.

```
my @texts;

print ("Enter text 1: ");
chomp(my $text1 = <STDIN>);
push @texts, $text1;
print ("Enter text 2: ");
chomp(my $text2 = <STDIN>);
push @texts, $text2;
print ("Enter text 3: ");
chomp(my $text3 = <STDIN>);
push @texts, $text3;

my @sorted_texts = sort { lc($b) cmp lc($a) } @texts;

print "Your texts are: @sorted_texts\n";
```

Since chomp can also operate on a list, you can just add one chomp call instead after reading all the input.

```
chomp(@texts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the main answer that you have $a and $b reversed?
The operative line should be:

```
my @sorted_texts = sort { lc($a) cmp lc($b) } @texts;
```